# What is the proper way to add vertical column lines between cells in angular AG Grid?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

Using Angular 11 and AG Grid.

I'd like to turn on vertical column lines between the cells. I see that I can style my own cells with cellStyle or cellClass … but is this the appropriate way to do it?

I could style something like …

```
{ border-right: 1px solid; }
```

Is there not an API/option to toggle an option like this on/off?  Doesn't make sense that row lines are automatic but column lines need to be manually styled. How am I supposed to know what the row color is to match it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue.  And I came to the same conclusion - that I had to include a style to achieve this as I couldn't find an option to toggle them on.

Instead of styling the cells with my own class, I overrode all the cells with an appropriate colour:

```
.ag-theme-balham .ag-header-cell,
.ag-theme-balham .ag-header-group-cell,
.ag-theme-balham .ag-ltr .ag-cell {
    border-right: 1px solid #D9DDDF;
}
```

(We've restyled the grid so alternate and selected rows are a different colour to standard, so this colour may not look correct for your colour scheme)

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation, Fletch. Cheers.

Comment: where are you placing your style override? I've tried all the css/scss locations and does not seem to have an effect. I can only do it via a cellStyle function in the columnDef declaration. I'd rather do it in the css.

Comment: I add a class to the <body> and use that in my main.scss.  So <body class="my-app"> and then .my-app .ag-theme-balham .ag-header-cell {border.....} in the scss file.  Let me know if you still have problems and I'll try and get a plunker for you